# Validation against multiple schemas using libxml2?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema, libxml2

I have got an xml file that needs to be validated against multiple xml schemas. The xml file should not be validated against one schema at a time, but rather against all at once. Is this possible with libxml2?

Edit: Currently I validate using `xmlSchemaValidateDoc`. Passing an `xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr` variable which seems to be capable of holding validation context for just one schema at a time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by validating "against all at once"? Why can't you simply validate against all the schemas in turn?

Comment: I would like to make sure that the xml file uses only types specified in the schema files...also the schemas reference each other.